# How to avoid change of ' to ’ in a code listing?

Tags: listings

I want that my PDF document contains a code snippet that looks like this:

```
char charValue = 'X';
```

I am using this code here:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java,escapechar=|]
    char charValue = 'X';
\end{lstlisting}
```

Unfortunately, the output in the PDF looks like this:

```
char charValue = ’X’;
```

`'` has been changed to `’`

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [LaTeX forum ⇒ Fonts & Character Sets ⇒ Listing package displays curly 'quotes' and tiny tildes ~](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4413):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
% http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4413
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,upquote=true}
\begin{document}
What's the following code do?
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java,escapechar=|]
    char charValue = 'X';
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]